# Permissions error in sandbox mode

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I created a sandbox ad account as described in https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2016/10/19/sandbox-ad-accounts/. I have generated an access token in the same section that lists my sandbox ad account.

I'm getting a permissions error when I request ad labels for the ad account. Anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_{{adAccountId}}/adlabels?access_token={{accessToken}}
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "FUB5kNhmuyX"
  }
}
```